# FFMPEG image to video with transition effects

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have used this command to concate multiple images with transition effects to create video.

```
"-y -f concat -safe 0 -i <txt file path> -filter_complex [0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out] -map [v] -shortest -vf fps=40 -pix_fmt yuv420p <video path>"
```

But it is showing error :

```
Stream specifier ':0' in filtergraph description [0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[out] matches no streams.
```

Here is my txt file

```
file '/storage/emulated/0/image1.jpg'
duration 5
file '/storage/emulated/0/image2.jpg'
duration 5
file '/storage/emulated/0/image3.jpg'
```

However if i am not applying any filter effect, it is successfully creating a video.

Comment: It should be `v=1:a=0` in the concat.

Comment: @Mulvya it gives error `Invalid file index 1 in filtergraph description [0:0][1:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[out]`

Comment: You only have one input - the text with the list.

Comment: But text file is having 3 images

Comment: But it's treated as one input by ffmpeg. See https://superuser.com/q/833232/114058 for help.

Answer (score 0):

Following command creates the video at a frame rate of 1 frame for 5 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -y -r 1/5 -i image1.jpg -i image2.jpg -i image3.jpg -filter_complex 'concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [out]' -map [out] -c:v libx264  output.mp4
```

Comment: I have replaced image1.jpg with my image path and output.mp4 to my mp4 file path but it gives `[NULL @ 0xb8e646c0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[out]'`

Comment: Not sure what is happening. What s ur ffmpeg version? Can you paste ffmpeg output for more details.